# Kernel vs. User threads

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

I am studying for a course on operating systems and I have a hard time understanding kernel and user threads. By what I understood, kernel threads are threads managed by the kernel, and hence can utilize multiprocessoring, while user threads are threads managed in the application level, and cant utilize multiprocessing. But then, lectures started to talk about mapping user threads to kernel threads. What does this mapping mean in this context? Thanks!

Comment: You may get possible answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178785/user-thread-and-kernel-thread

Comment: Thanks! Question can now be closed.