# Do any operating systems utilize user threads only?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, kernel, hybrid, userspace

We're reading a basic/simple guide to Operating Systems in my CS class. The text gives multiple examples of OSs that use 1:1 threading, and some that formerly did hybrid/ M:N. But there are no examples of user threads/N:1.

This isn't a homework question, I'm just genuinely curious if this is or was a thing. Have any OSs utilized exclusively user threads? Or is there any software or programming language that does? It seems like with the right scheduling it could be very fast? Thank you!

Spent forever on Google and can't find any explicit answer to this!

Comment: Please also check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331719/how-does-n-1-threading-model-work

Comment: Android must do this. There is basically one JVM so everything must be a thread.

Comment: "User threads" (a.k.a., "N:1", a.k.a., "green threads") means that the application program is entirely responsible for creating and managing its own threads. The OS _kernel_ has no knowledge of them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#Threading_models If green threads are supported by some user-mode library that is provided as standard in some OS distro, then I guess it's a matter of opinion whether or not "the OS" supports them.

Answer (score 1):

> Do any operating systems utilize user threads only?

No (and not in the way you're expecting, but by definition). Whatever a program feels like doing in user-space is none of the operating system's business and can not be considered something the OS itself does.

Essentially there's 3 cases:

- the OS is a single-tasking OS (and user-space programs use libraries or whatever to provide threading if/when they want it). E.g. MS-DOS.
- the OS is a multi-tasking OS, where the OS only knows about processes (and user-space programs use libraries or whatever to provide threading if/when they want it). E.g. early Unix.
- the OS/kernel provides threads (leading to 1:1 or M:N).

> It seems like with the right scheduling it could be very fast?

User-space threading isn't "very fast", it's significantly worse for most things. The reasons are:

- it can't work when there's multiple CPUs (so the nice 8-core CPU you're currently using becomes 87.5% wasted). You need a "M:N threading" at a minimum to avoid this performance disaster.
- it breaks thread priorities badly - e.g. CPU/s wasting time doing unimportant work while important work isn't being done, because one process doesn't know anything about threads that belong to any other process (or their priorities). The scheduler must be aware of all threads to avoid this performance disaster (and if one process knows about all threads belonging to all other processes it becomes a security disaster).
- almost all thread switches are caused by devices (threads having to wait for disk, network, keyboard, "wall clock time", ... causing scheduler to have to find some other thread to run; and things a thread was waiting for occurring causing the thread to be able to run again and possibly preempt less important work that was running at the time); and all devices involve the kernel (even for micro-kernels where kernel is needed to pass messages, etc); so almost all thread switches involve the kernel. By doing threading in user-space you just end up with kernel wasting time notifying user-space (so user-space can do some scheduling) instead of kernel doing the scheduling itself (without wasting time on notifications).

User-space threading is better for rare situations where kernel doesn't have to be involved anyway, which is limited to:

- thread creation and termination; but only if memory (for thread state, thread stack, thread local storage) is pre-allocated and recycled, and only if "thread recycling" isn't done (e.g. pre-create kernel threads and put them back in a "free thread pool" instead of telling kernel to terminate and create them again later).
- locking (e.g. mutexes) where all threads using the lock belong to the same process; where 1 kernel thread (and no need for locks) is still better than "multiple user-space threads (sharing 1 kernel thread) fighting for the same lock with extra pointless overhead".

Comment: Yeah, a system with only 'user threads' could not effectively manage CPU or I/O resources, so, pretty well pointless:)