# java.io.InputStream - read()

Tags: java, multithreading, java-io

The `read()` method blocks until a byte is available on stream for an input resource(keyboard/file/network/program).

```
public abstract int read() throws IOException
```

---

1) For a single threaded Java program, Does blocking of `read()` enable kernel to move [java process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) to [blocked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_state) state?

2) For a multi-threaded Java program, Does blocking of `read()` on one thread allow other threads to occupy CPU slice? Having *java process* continue in *Running* state until it's CPU time slice.

Comment: Realistically, you will not be able to find a single-threaded Java process.  The JVM itself spawns multiple threads.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Are you talking about JVM system threads? GC/compiler/VM/.. that will be part of my java program in runtime

Comment: Processes does not have states like that, only threads do.

Comment: Processes have states in unix-like OSs, at least as far as users are concerned. sleeping, zombie, stopped, etc. Check out the `ps` man page, "PROCESS STATE CODES".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Do you mean, user level thread(java's `t.start()`-> C's `pthread_create()`) map to kernel level thread? OS schedules kernel level threads, with it's respective [threading model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324668/why-does-os-require-maintain-kernel-threads)

Comment: Please stop re-posting this question.

Comment: @PaulHicks An unfortunate and confusing historical relic that exists only within the `ps` command. There is simply no way a process can sleep -- that's a category error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For a single threaded Java program, Does blocking of read() enable kernel to move java process to blocked state?

There is no such thing as a single-threaded Java program, but if there was, yes.

> For a multi-threaded Java program, Does blocking of read() on one thread allow other threads to occupy CPU slice?

Of course. Otherwise threads would be pointless.

> Having java process continue in Running state until it's CPU time slice.

Yes.